# Oracle SQL: Find the Parent of a child using Hierarchy queries

Tags: sql, oracle

My intention is to find the Topmost Parent ID and assign that id to all the childs under that tree. For example

```
LOSER     WINNER
 1          2
 2          3
 3          4
 5          7
 6          7
```

My Output should be like as shown Below

```
LOSER        WINNER
  1            4
  2            4
  3            4
  5            7
  6            7
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way. Perhaps not the most efficient (it could be made more efficient with a `START WITH` clause and running down the tree rather than up, but since you don't have rows for the "roots" of the tree as `loser`, with `null` for `winner`, it's just a bit more complicated). If you don't have a lot of input data to process, this may suffice.

Note that the `with` clause is NOT PART OF THE QUERY; instead, I use it only so that I can have the test data right there in the code (instead of creating a table and inserting into it).

```
with
  inputs ( loser, winner ) as (
    select 1, 2 from dual union all
    select 2, 3 from dual union all
    select 3, 4 from dual union all
    select 5, 7 from dual union all
    select 6, 7 from dual
  )
select     connect_by_root loser as loser, winner
from       inputs
where      connect_by_isleaf = 1
connect by loser = prior winner
;

     LOSER     WINNER
---------- ----------
         1          4
         2          4
         3          4
         5          7
         6          7
```